# How to use the JRE with Tor in Tails OS

Tags: configuration, tails, java

I have a executable .jar file which I want to execute. It needs internet access, but it seems like it is the only program wich is not able to access the internet. I use the standard configuration for the JRE which comes preinstalled on tails (openjdk-7-jre). I suppose this is a problem with the JRE configuration but I was not able to find a way to change it in a way that would make it work.
Do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Have you tried just wrapping it in `torsocks`? It *can* cause problems with *some* applications but it may serve your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try Oracle JDK/JRE - OpenJDK causes such a weird problems sometimes even nowdays. Second - try to use Tor as a proxy, set these properties:

- java.net.useSystemProxies=true
- http.proxyHost=proxy-**ip**
- http.proxyPort=proxy-port

Comment: Where do I set these props? In the jcontrol file?

Comment: or in the command line switches

Comment: it says "unrecognised option: java.net.useSystemProxies=true". Same with the other 2 properties

Comment: you have to use -Dproperty=value , see the official docs for details, it's [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: ok the properties are set now, thanks. Still it doesnt work. I am probably using the wrong ip and port. I'll try it again tomorrow

Comment: try to use HTTP/HTTPS proxy polipo - remember that Tor itself is a SOCKS proxy which is - unfortunately - is not properly supported by JRE out-of-the-box. You can find polipo [here at it's official site](https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/)

Comment: Tor isn't an http proxy, so you may wish to try `socksProxyHost=127.0.0.1` and `socksProxyPort=9050` *or* just specify the `java.net.useSystemProxies=true`. Trying to get use an http proxy will likely fail and conflict with other settings.

Comment: @canonizingironize as far as you can see, `useSystemProxies` haven't helped. `socksProxyHost=127.0.0.1` and `socksProxyPort=9050` are not worked always as they should for me in OpenJDK, but polipo gave me a helping hand in such cases countless times.

Comment: You won't be able to run polipo under Tails, at least not in any reasonably safe way and saying "useSystemProxies" and then explicitly specifying an http proxy is likely to conflict. Unclear which it's trying to use if both are specified.